# Shared Constraint Does Not Complie

Tags: grails

Happy Stuck At Home Day,

I follow the example in this grails 4.0.4 doc to setup shared constraint.
I create a new file **runtime.groovy** in the **conf** folder, and type the lines.

It does not work and says it cannot find the main() method in the runtime.groovy file.

Would you show me how to create shared constraints please?

Thanks and stay safe at home.

https://docs.grails.org/4.0.4/guide/validation.html#sharingConstraints

Global Constraints
In addition to defining constraints in domain classes, command objects and other validateable classes, you can also define them in grails-app/conf/runtime.groovy:

```
grails.gorm.default.constraints = {
    '*'(nullable: true, size: 1..20)
    myShared(nullable: false, blank: false)
}
```

Comment: `"Shared Constraint Does Not Complie"` - What compilation error is generated?

Comment: Missing the main() method in the runtime.groovy file.

Comment: I believe you, but it really doesn't make sense to me that the compiler would be saying that.  I am sorry I can't help.

Comment: np.  I google and see that an older doc says to put the shared constraint to the Config.groovy file.  I try that also. It does not work.  I have given up this idea.